# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|$ diverges. Then Radius of convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Suppose $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that
>   $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|$
>   diverges. Then the radius of convergence of the power series
>   $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$ .

Given answer: Radius of Convergence($R)=1$.
My attempt:-
There exists a natural number $N$ such that $\forall n\ge N \implies |a_n|<1$
(because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges $\implies \lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$)
So, $\lim_{n\to \infty}|a_n|^{1/n}\le1\implies R\ge1$)

Similarly, There exists a natural number $M$ such that $\forall n\ge M \implies \sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|>1$ ($\because$ $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ diverges ). How to complete the proof?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is NOT a power series. It makes no sense to talk about its radius of convergence. My guess is that you're asked for the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the Typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some basic facts about power series: if $R$ is the radius of convergence of $\sum a_n x^{n}$ then the series converges absolutely for $|x| <R$ and diverges for $|x| >R$. The first fact implies that $R \leq 1$ and the second fact implies that $R\geq 1$.

Comment: Sir, Which factor implies $R\leq 1$.? I am not able to prove it.

Comment: If R >1 then the series will converge absolutely when $x=1$.

Comment: Sir, please see my attempt. I got $R\ge 1$.  I don't get your point. How do I prove $R\leq 1$. Can you please help me?

Comment: @Unknownx If $R>1$ then $\sum a_n x^{n}$ converges absolutely for $|x| <R$, in particular for $x=1$. This is a basic fact about power series. Since it is given that $|sum a_n$ is not absolutely convergent it follows that $R$ cannot be greater than $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much.