# Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_n$ where $\sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^n a_n$ converges, but $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^n2_na_n$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, summation, power-series

From this example: [$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|$ diverges. Then Radius of convergence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220475/sum-n-1-infty-a-n-converges-and-sum-n-1-inftya-n-diverges-then-ra)

I believe I'm supposed to leverage these two statements to show that $R \leq |z|$ and $R \geq |z|$ for some $z \in \mathbb{C}$, but their choice of 1 seems arbitrary, so I'm not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$.

Suppose that $R>2$. Then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n2^na_n$ is convergent, a contradiction. Hence $R \le 2.$

Suppose that $R <2$. Then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^na_n$ is divergent, a contradiction. Hence $R =2.$